# Put multiple UILabels into an array

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

In my app I currently have 9 labels on my storyboard, each showing a different value. (The values are stored in an array). As far as I know, each label has to be connected from the storyboard to the viewcontroller file separately, which makes my code look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var xValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var yValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var zValue: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var maxXValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var maxYValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var maxZValue: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var minXValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minYValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minZValue: UILabel!
```

And to set the values, I need to manually do:

```
xValue.text = arr[0]
yValue.text = arr[1]
...
minYValue = arr[7]
minZValue = arr[8]
```

Is there a way to connect multiple labels from the storyboard into an array so that I can simply do something like:

```
for i in 0...8 {
    labelArray[i] = arr[i]
}
```

Comment: LabelArray.append(xValue)

Comment: You do not need 9 separate outlets. Look into `@IBOutletCollection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rmaddy mentioned in a comment you can use an outlet collection:

```
@IBOutlet private var labels: [UILabel]!
```

Then in your storyboard `labels` will show up under `Outlet Collections` when right-clicking your `ViewController`, and you can link multiple labels:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the UILabel into an array, like this:

```
let labelArray = [xValue, yValue, zValue]
for i in 0..<labelArray.count-1{
    labelArray[i] = arr[i]
}
```

Comment: An easier way would be `for label in labelArray`.